# How to access a Date Variable from Service class in Controller

Tags: grails

I have the following model class

```
public class User{

    String firstName
    String lastName
    Date startDate
    Date endDate
    static constraint(){
           firstname(nullable:true)
           lastname(nullable:true)
           startDate
           endDate
     }
    }
```

My Service class

```
  public class UserService {
    public void addUser(String firstName, String lastName, Date startDate, Date endDate){
    User user = new User()
    user.firstName=firstName
    user.lastName=lastName
    user.startDate=startDate
    user.endDate=endDate
     }
    }
```

Now my Question is how can i access my Date variables  in my controller
My controller class

```
public class UserController {
def applyService
def register = applyService.addUser(params.firstName.toString(), params.lastName.toString()
```

now I don't know how to access my `startDate` and `endDate` variable  .... i can't access them using params because they are not string...any solution.  am new to grails

Comment: when you call service method.?can you post full action?

Comment: This might help: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2012/01/grails-goodness-date-request-parameter.html

Comment: i didn't go any more. as u see i accessed the `firsName` and `lastName` variable by using `params.firstName` and `params.lastName`  then i want to include the date variables.  how do i do that??

Comment: have u tested my answer , i just used a date ? or post ur gps file ?

Comment: `<p>
    <label for="startDate"> From </label>     
    <input type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate" class="datePicker" value="${user?.startDate}">
   </p>
   <p>
    <label for="endDate"> To </label>
    <input type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate" class="datePicker" value="${user?.endDate}">
   </p>`

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I will change as follow.

```
def register = applyService.addUser(params.firstName.toString(),params.lastName.toString()
,parseDate(params['startDate'] ,
 parseDate(parmas['endDate']))
```

And assuming you are using grails version > 2.3 change as follow

A setting in Config.groovy

```
grails.databinding.dateFormats = [
        'MMddyyyy', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S', "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"]


import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat

public class User{

    String firstName
    String lastName
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S')  // or any format you like
    Date startDate
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S') 
    Date endDate
    static constraint(){
           firstname(nullable:true)
           lastname(nullable:true)
           startDate
           endDate
     }
    }
```

Cheers!

Comment: i used it as u put it but it is returning the following erorr. `No signature of method: com.registeration.admin.ApplyController.parseDate() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [10-09-2012]`

Answer (score 0):

You are leaving aside one of the most powerful features of Grails: [Data Binding](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#dataBinding)

I would do something like:

```
class UserController {

    def userService

    def save = {
        def user = new User(params)
        userService.addUser(user)
    }

}
```

When instantiating a Domain Object with the param maps on a Controller, Grails will figure it out for you what is the proper type of the User's fields and will set them accordingly. On your service you can simply persist the instance.

I would recommend you to have a look to [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) as well.